# Write a method to work out the sum of the first n odd numbers

Tags: java, loops, sum

First of all let me say I am quite new to programming its been my second week since I started so if you see any bad practice or error in code please accept my apologies.

I want to print sum of first n odd numbers. But so far I can only do the sum of odd number up to the given number. kindly help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter the number : ");
    int num1 = userInput.nextInt();

    int sum = sumOfOdd(num1);
    System.out.println("sum of first " +num1 + " odd numbers is " + sum);

    userInput.close();
}

static int sumOfOdd(int num)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++)
    {
        if(i % 2 != 0)
        {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
}
```

Comment: You do know that the sum of the first `n` odd numbers is `n*n`...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have to use a loop at all

```
static int sumOfOdd(int num) {
    return num*num;
}
```

For Any Arithmetic Progression, the sum of numbers is given by,

> Sn=1/2×n[2a+(n-1)×d]

Where,

Sn= Sum of n numbers

n = n numbers

a = First term of an A.P

d= Common difference in an A.P

Using above formula we can derive this quick formula to calculate sum of  first n odd numbers,

> Sn(odd numbers)= n²

Comment: Thanks for your help. It was easy just take the square of the the number and you are good to go. But I do admit, it was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 3):

Try this it uses a [**for loop**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) that increments by two to only account for odd numbers.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the value of n: ");
    int n = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("The sum of the first " + n + " odd numbers is: " + sumOfOddNumbers(n));
  }

  public static int sumOfOddNumbers(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < n*2; i+=2) {
      sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
  }
}
```

**Example usage:**

```
Enter the value of n:  5
The sum of the first 5 odd numbers is: 25
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
static int sumOfOdd(int num) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        sum += i*2+1;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

It sums up all odd numbers until the limit is reached.

With `i*2+1` you get the next odd number. Then you add it to the sum.

Tested with `System.out.println(sumOfOdd(4));` and got the expected result `16` (1+3+5+7)

Answer (score 1):

Change the counter to the number of times you add an odd number to the sum value...

```
static int sumOfOdd(int num) {
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    do {
        if(i % 2 != 0) {
            sum += i;
            count++;
        }
        i++;
    } while (count < num);
    return sum;
}
```

Or even cleaner:

```
static int sumOfOdd(int num) {
    int sum=0;
    for (int i=1;i<num*2;i+=2) {
        sum=sum+i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should count how many numbers have you added and in the condition to check if count of numbers you summed is less or equal than your n. Just add the counter in your for loop and set condition to: `count <= num` and it should work. 
Every time you add a number to the sum increment the count by `count++`. 
The code suppose to look like this:

```
static int sumOfOdd(int num)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0, count= 0; count <= num; i++)
    {
        if(i % 2 != 0)
        {
            sum += i;
            count++;
        }
    }
return sum;
}
```

I haven't checked it, but it should be correct

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know how many loop cycles are required you have to change the exit condition of the **for** loop.
Or you can use a **while** loop exploiting the same exit condition.

```
static int sumOfOdd(int num){
  int sum = 0;
  int counter = 0;
  int currentNumber = 0;
  while (counter<num){
      if(currentNumber % 2 != 0){
          sum += currentNumber;
          counter++;
      }
      currentNumber++;

  }
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code you'd be using:

```
public class YourClass {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter the number : ");
        int num1 = userInput.nextInt();

        int sum = sumOfOdd(num1);
        System.out.println("sum of first " +num1 + " odd numbers is " + sum);

        userInput.close();
    }

    static int sumOfOdd(int num)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0;; i++)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            if(i % 2 != 0)
            {
                counter++;
                sum += i;
            }
            if(counter == num) return sum;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative.

```
static int sumOfOdd(int num) {
    int sum = 0;
    int last = 2*num-1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= last; i+=2){
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Obviously `return num*num;` is the most efficient but if you're obliged to use a loop then this method avoids a `*` inside the loop.

This will be a tiny (tiny) bit more efficient than:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i){
        sum += 2*i+1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

class karan{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int i = n;
        int sumOddNumber = n * i;

        System.out.println(n*i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32238228)